# How to write new nodes to json file on server using php

Tags: php, json

How can i handle an array sent by jquery to put into an existing nested json file with php?
I can send the data with jquery but all i can manage is php overwriting the file or adding the data to the end of the document, i need to put new data in the nested structure of the json file.

My script looks like this;

```
<?php
$postdata = $_POST['data'];
$postdata = json_encode($postdata);
file_put_contents('json/user.json', $postdata);
?>
```

My json had a nested structure like;

```
"{\"users\":
    [{\"user\":
         [{\"id\":\"martijn\",
           \"pw\":\"password\",
           \"name\":\"user3\",
           \"icons\":
              [{\"bookmarks\":\"bookmark3\",
                \"notes\":\"note3\"
           }]
         }]
    }]
}"
```

I would like to add another user to the users, how would i do that with php?

My jQuery request and the data to send;

```
var newUser = [{
                    user: [{
                        id: username,
                        pw: password,
                        name: "user3",
                        icons: [{
                            bookmarks: "bookmark3",
                            notes: "note3"
                        }]
                    }]
                }];


                var userSetup = JSON.stringify(newUser);

                $.ajax({
                    url: themeUrl + '/script.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { 
                        data: newUser,
                    },
                    dataType: 'json'
                });
```

Comment: By the looks of it you should really be using a proper database.  Using the filesystem in this way is first-page, first-paragraph of Bottlenecks 101.

Answer (score 0):

This a bit tricky situation,

You need to make use of these steps inorder to do that..

- First check if the file `user.json` exists by using `file_exists()`
- If it does.. Just read all the content from it using the `file_get_contents()`
- Now `json_decode()` it and store that in an array.
- Now grab the `$_POST['data']` and add it to the earlier decoded array.
- Now you have to do the final `json_encode()` it to a string.
- Finally write to the `user.json` file using `file_put_contents()`. [No need of the `FILE_APPEND` flag]

The coding part...

```
<?php 

if(file_exists('json/user.json'))
{
$cont = file_get_contents('json/user.json'); 
$usr_array = json_decode($cont,1);
    foreach($_POST['data'] as $val)
    {
        $usr_array[]=$val;
    }
$newData = json_encode($usr_array); 
file_put_contents('json/user.json', $newData ); 
}
else
{
    die('File does not exist !');
}
```

Comment: Tried updating my script and removed file_append but now its overwriting or adding 'Array' at the end of the file. (depending if i use file_append or not)

Comment: <?php
   
 
 $db = file_get_contents('json/user.json', true);
 $db = json_decode($db);
 $database = Array($db);
 
 $users = $database->users;
 
 $postdata = $_POST['data'];
   
 $newData = $users . $postdata;
 
 $newData = json_encode($newData);
 
 file_put_contents('json/user.json', $newData );
?>

Comment: this doesnt add anything in my file. do i need to use json.stringify in the ajax post request?

Comment: Seems like the `file_exists` fails. Can you try commenting the `if` statement and give a try ?

Comment: still doesnt do anything

Comment: added some more info on what im tryin to achieve